# Why can't I use background-image: url("img/1.jpg"); to using local images

Tags: css

The code is like below. I have already put the image "1.jpg" into that file name "img". But in my website, this image doesn't show up. However, I found that if I use the images from Internet, it will show up. Could someone figure out the problem?

[image]

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url("img/1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: can you post a picture of the directory structure. To see where the CSS, HTML and image is in relation to each other

Comment: Open your browsers inspector, and see if the image is being loaded. It is probable you have messed up the image location, and are getting a 404

Comment: Probably because of the wrong relative path between CSS file and image file. Check project directory and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Probably `/img/1.jpg` if the css file is inside its own dedicated folder. So using the code the OP has would search for `root/css/img/1.jpg` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder structure like:

```
* CSS File
* img/
  * 1.jpg
```

What you are doing is right. But if you have:

```
* css/
  * CSS File
* img/
  * 1.jpg
```

Then you need to change it to:

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url("../img/1.jpg");
}
```

The `..` in the url goes one level up in the directory structure. This is where it can find the `img` folder. It then finds image `1.jpg`

Comment: Yes. The folder structure like:

Comment: @jzhangnu Like how? First or second?